# Извлечь ссылки на видео из плейлиста YouTube

Tags: python, youtube

Как получить все ссылки на видео в плейлисте ютуб на питон?

Comment: Использовать API самого YouTube вестимо.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pytube import Playlist

link = Playlist('Ссылка на плейлист')

for i in link.video_urls:
    print(i)
```